Is it possible to prevent CMake from installing the cpack files in the installation subdirectory?
I want to have a set of files installed to a specific subdirectory, build/my_project, when I run cmake --install . and the same files included in two RPMs when I run cpack .. Unfortunately, cmake is also installing the RPM files in the build/my_project subdirectory.
This is the subdirectory structure I want in my build directory
build/

|-- my_project
    |-- lib64
    |-- include
                 

This is what I'm getting
build/

|-- my_project
    |-- lib64
    |   |-- my_project
    |-- include
        |-- my_project

The libs and header files are installed in the appropriate subdirectories, including in the extra my_project subdirectories.
Here are the install commands in CMakeLists.txt
install(TARGETS my_project DESTINATION lib64/my_project COMPONENT lib)
install(TARGETS my_project DESTINATION lib64 COMPONENT install)

install(TARGETS headers DESTINATION include/my_project COMPONENT headers)
install(TARGETS headers DESTINATION include COMPONENT install)

The relevant cpack commands are
...
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr)
set(CPACK_RPM_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL lib headers)

include(CPack)

and I set the install prefix with
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX my_project) 
                 

The two RPMs are generated correctly with the /usr prefix, and they don't contain the "install" components.
Is there a way to execute install commands with specific components (in this case "install") when I run cmake --install . and execute other install commands, with other component labels, when I run cpack .?
